# Estimation of parameter $\widehat\beta$ in the linear model

Tags: regression, self-study, bayesian, estimation, linear-model

Consider the simple linear model $Y=X\beta+\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon\sim N_n(0,\sigma^2I).$

It known that $\widehat\beta=(X^tX)^{-1}X^tY$.

Also,

$$\pi(\beta\mid Y)\propto\Gamma\left[\frac{1}{2}(v+r) \right] v^{-r/2}S^{-r} \left[1+\frac{(\beta-\widehat\beta) X^tX(\beta-\widehat\beta)} {vS^2}\right]^{-(v+r)/2}$$

which is the kernel of student's t distribution.

$\beta$ is a r.v. with student's t distribution.

mean $=$ mode $=$ median $=\widehat\beta$

The last beta (mean $=$ mode $=$ median $=\widehat \beta$), Is the same as $\widehat\beta=(X^tX)^{-1}X^tY$ or is it other?

Supposing it is the same, then I cannot see the sense of calculating the prior,marginal of beta, etc. because this $\widehat\beta=(X^tX)^{-1}X^tY$ can be known without bayesian calculations.

What is the point doing the bayesian calculations then?

Comment: I edited my question hoping now it's clear. Is it now clear?

Comment: What "last beta"?

Comment: @Tim the above one, $\hat\beta=$mode=mean=median

Comment: @Tim I think it's not because $\hat\beta=(X^tX)^{-1}X^tY$ will return a $2\times 1$ vector and it should be 16 values, for each $\beta_i$. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You quote OLS solution for estimating regression parameters. If you have two parameters, it will estimate two, if you have sixteen, it will estimate sixteen. I don't see how your example is related and how "mean=mode=median" is related to anything else in your question. Fitted values are not parameters.

Comment: @Tim Suppose you have the r.v. $\beta$ with distribution student's t multivariate, hence mean=mode=median$=\hat\beta$, how do you calculate manually the  $\hat\beta?$

Comment: You already quoted OLS estimator for parameters. You also seem to be mixing Bayesian scenario where parameters are treated as random variables and frequentist approach.

Comment: @Tim Why? what am I doing wrong

Comment: I don't know. Your question is confusing. You ask how to estimate parameters, but at the same time you quote formula for this.